# How to bind shiny app to run on specific computer only

Tags: r, security, shiny

I need to make sure that my shiny app will run on a specific computer only. I can retrieve different types of computer's information by using `system('ipconfig /all')` function  but I need to make sure that this information can't be changed.
For example, I thought of retrieving the Ethernet adapter Ethernet  Physical Address, will it be safe enough?

Comment: If an app in on a local computer, what's to stop the user from  editing your `*.R` files to remove this restriction? I would say this isn't safe at all as any shiny app on a computer can be edited freely.

Comment: @Michael Bird, The *.R files are stored on cloud and are downloaded to a local computer on demand so the user doesn't have the *.R files.

Comment: but once they have downloaded the `server.R` file, they run the app themselves? If that's the case then they can just remove the authentication. A much better idea would be to host the app on a server with authentication.

Comment: @Michael Bird, that's true but i need to be sure that access for the app will be from a specific computer only.